# E-mail enviado pela função phpmailer vai para spam

Tags: php, phpmailer

O código abaixo envia o e-mail corretamente, no entanto, vai para a caixa de spam, seja para Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook etc. Será que o problema está no código ou no servidor que envia o e-mail?! Só para constar o servidor que utilizo está em http e não https.

```
<?php
//Chama a classe
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

if(isset($_POST['send'])){

    //Variáveis enviadas pelo formulário
    $nome = $_POST["name"];
    $emailUsuario = $_POST["email"];
    $assunto = $_POST["subject"];
    $sugestao = $_POST["message"];

    //Instanciando o objeto
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
    $mail->Host = "mail.meudominio.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Autenticação
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->Username = 'atendimento@meudominio.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
    $mail->Password = 'senha'; // Senha da caixa postal utilizada

    //Define o remetente
    $mail->From = "atendimento@meudominio.com"; 
    $mail->FromName = "Nome Empresa";

    //Define os destinatário(s)
    $mail->AddAddress('destinatario@gmail.com', 'Nome');
    $mail->AddAddress('destinatario@gmail.com');
    $mail->AddCC('email@gmail.com', 'Nome Nome'); // cópia normal
    $mail->AddBCC('email@gmail.com', 'Nome Nome');// cópia oculta

    //Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

    //Texto e Assunto em formato HTML
    $mail->Subject  = $assunto; // Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Body = '<html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:#d0e2f4;color:#808080;" align="center">
            <div style="width:70%;background-color:white;padding:20px;" align="left">
                <p><font face="arial">Nome: ' . $nome . '</font></p>
                <p><font face="arial">Email: ' . $emailUsuario . '</font></p>
                <p><font face="arial">Assunto: ' . $assunto . '</font></p>
                <hr style="color:#f2f2f2;">
                <br>
                <p style="color:#808080;font-size:14px;"><font face="arial">' . $sugestao . '</font></p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div style="font-size:12px;" align="center">
                <p><font face="arial">Nome Empresa</font></p>
                <p><font face="arial">Slogan Empresa</font></p>
                <p><font face="arial">www.siteempresa.com</font></p>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>                                                          
        </body>
    </html> ';

    //Aqui faz o envio da mensagem
    $enviado = $mail->Send();

    //Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
}
```

?>

Comment: Além dos links mencionados acima, um jeito bom de saber qual a razão de ter caido no spam é abrir o email e visualizar o arquivo RAW dele (ver o email original, com cabeçalhos e tudo o mais)

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação. Vou reorganizar o código.

Comment: Antes do código, olhe o email original que caiu no spam. A explicação provavelmente está lá, e nem tem relação com o código, e sim com um problema no DNS ou no servidor (que é sua pergunta inicial, e tem explicações pelas diversas respostas linkadas acima)

Comment: Justo no momento minha caixa de spam está limpa, mas se aparecer algo logo, mando um print de exemplo de onde olhar.